# Access to an array items?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I have a variable that contains :
Sometimes array of strings and sometimes array of array of strings 
e.g:

```
var words = a LINQ to XML query;
//words == { "01", "02", "03", ... }
//or
//words == { {"01", "02", "03"}, {"04", "05", "06"}, ... }
```

Now , I wanna access to each item in the `words` array with a `for statement`
Could you please guide me ?
Thanks

Comment: What's the type of the `words` variable?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it's an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: please see the edit...)

If you don't actually know beforehand whether you've got a string array or an array of arrays of strings, you'll need to *conditionally* call `SelectMany`:

```
string[][] multi = words as string[][];
string[] flattened = multi == null ? words : multi.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Note that in this case if you *change* the contents of `flattened`, that will either change `words` (if that was already flat) or just change a copy (if it was a jagged array). If you want to make it consistent, you could call `words.ToArray()` in second operand of the conditional operator:

```
string[] flattened = 
    multi == null ? words.ToArray() : multi.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Is there no way you can avoid the ambiguity to start with though? In particular, if you're in control over the LINQ to XML queries involved, you should be able to make them give a consistent result type.

EDIT: I've just realised that if you don't know the type of the data to start with, then `words` is presumably declared as just `object` or perhaps `IEnumerable`. In that case, you'd want something like this:

```
public string[] Flatten(object words)
{
    string[][] multi = words as string[][];
    if (multi != null)
    {
        return multi.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
    }
    string[] single = words as string[];
    if (single != null)
    {
        return single.ToArray(); // Defensive copy; remove if not needed
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be string[] or string[][]");
}
```

This is still really icky - you should definitely try to make the queries give you some consistent result type instead.

Comment: @Jon - I'm not sure the ambiguity is a problem. I tried `SelectMany` on just a `string[]` and a `string[][]` and it worked in both cases.

Comment: SelectMany on a string[] will give you an `IEnumerable<char>` which isn't what you want.

Comment: You're right. I only used single character strings in my test so it looked great. That was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the second form to the first using SelectMany:

```
string[] words = words2.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: ... with a call to `ToArray()` at the end, of course, if you want to get that to compile. Or just use `IEnumerable<string>` or `var` otherwise.